# Java how to use a double or a string?

Tags: java

Alright so I'm trying to get the user to input either the word "random" or a number (0.01) for a sales tax and my prompt can only use either keybd.next() or keybd.nextDouble() so how would I easily do this?

```
public void calculateSalesReceipt(){
    System.out.println("Enter the sales tax percentage (ex. 0.08 for 8%) or type \"random\" for a random number: ");
    double tax = keybd.nextDouble();
    if(tax < 0){
        System.out.println("You must enter a value equal to or greater than 0!");
    }else{
    getFinalPricePreTax();
    total = total;
    taxcost = total * tax;
    double finaltotal = total * taxcost;
    System.out.println("Sales Receipt");
    System.out.println("-------------");
    for(Item currentProduct : shoppingBag){
        System.out.println(currentProduct.getName() + " - " + currentProduct.getUnits() + " units " + " - $" + currentProduct.getCost());
    }
    System.out.println("Total cost: $" + total);
    System.out.println("Total tax: $" + taxcost);
    System.out.println("Total cost with tax: $" + finaltotal);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `keybd` is a `Scanner`

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

You need to use `hasNextDouble()` to determine if it's a double or not and then act accordingly.

Option B (though you say your requirements exclude this) is to simply read it as a `String` then do the conversion afterward with `Double.valueOf(String)` or `Double.parseString(String)` static methods and catching the `NumberFormatException` to determine validity.

**Edit based on comments from OP:**

```
System.out.println("Enter the sales tax ... blah blah");
if (keybd.hasNextDouble())
{
    double tax = keybd.nextDouble();    
    // Do double stuff
}
else
{
   // Get String and Do string stuff
}
```

Comment: This is helpful but I don't know how to use it lol.  Yes, I am using a scanner

Comment: Don't know how to use ... what?

Comment: I've edited to show you, but I would be remis not to recommend a basic intro to programming book or at the very least recommend you go through the Java tutorials provided by Oracle. Not understanding how to use classes and methods is beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: This works the first time, but if i run it again, it just skips the asking part and calculates a random number?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Double.parseDouble(String)` to convert a string value to a double. If the string does not represent a double value, a `NumberFormatException` will be thrown.

```
double d;
if ("random".equals(string)) {
  d = 4.0; // random
} else {
  try {
    d = Double.parseDouble(string);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // !
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keybd.next()` to grab the token as a string.  Then check if its a double.

Sample code:

```
String input= keybd.next();
try{
  Double input= Double.parseDouble(input);
  //execute code with double variable

} catch (ParseException ex){
  //call string handler code
}
```